# JQuery updown strange behavior

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Simple dialog:

```
$j('#appointment-time-dialog').dialog({
    closeText: 'hide',
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Appointment Time',
    autoOpen: false
    });
$j('#appointment-time-hours').updown(0, 23, 0);
$j('#appointment-time-minutes').updown(0, 59, 0);
```

I have found interesting behaviour of that feature: both up buttons counts from 0 to 8 and then goes to 0, and down buttons can count down to 9 and then goes to its maximum (23 and 59).

I can ever to find out where "to digg" in order to find solution..

P.S: Used JQuery 1.7.1

Comment: sure.  A demo would clearly demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truth was on the surface =)

Before setting incremented/decremented value I used to add "0" before new string value (for any values 1..9 in order to simulate watch's minutes) and then **parseInt()** them.

But preceding zero makes octal digits.

So be careful and use **parseInt(value, scale)** (in my case I need to use parseInt(value, 10))